# Can one select multiple elements in JavaScript just like you do in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, multipleselection

The situation is this: I have a function which accepts as a parameter the name of a class, just like in JQuery: select(".item"); Inside the function I use
`document.getElementsByClassName()` 
However if I use select(".item, .prize"), it does not work since you cannot use documents.getElementsByClassName() to select multiple classes. Is there a way to select multiple elements using only JavaScript?

Comment: What doesn't work. What is the exact behaviour, and the expected behaviour and the code related to the problem.

Comment: izstas gave the solution! I wanted to select multiple elements using only JavaScript code. In JQuery you do it $(".item,.prize"); I wanted an equivalent in JavaScript and querySelectorAll(".item,.prize")   worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is what you're looking for:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".item, .prize")
```

This should return you a list of all elements which have either class `item` or `prize`.